# External script [Clutch Widget] integration

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router, external-script

After changing route and come back to the page where it locates, the widget disappears in UI, But reloading the page render the widget.
Followed this blog: https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/how-to-load-third-party-scripts-in-nuxt-js/. But not getting solution.

```
<div
    class="clutch-widget mt-6"
    data-url="https://widget.clutch.co"
    data-widget-type="1"
    data-height="40"
    data-darkbg="1"
    data-clutchcompany-id="1715171"
  />

    head () {
  return {
    script: [
      {
        hid: 'clutch',
        type: "text/javascript",
        src:"https://widget.clutch.co/static/js/widget.js",
        defer: true,
        // async: false,
        // Changed after script load
        callback: () => {
          console.log('head: ', this.isClutchWidgetLoaded)
          this.isClutchWidgetLoaded = true
         }
      },
    ]
  }
},
```

Comment: You don't want to load it in the default layout or in the Nuxt config file? Why in a specific page?

Comment: I have tried in default layout or in nuxt config . But  the result is the same. It needs to refresh the page.

Comment: How do you change route?

Comment: using nuxt-link. Like <nuxt-link to="/contacts"></nuxt-link>

Comment: What is this widget exactly and why is this not working in the default layout? You want to have it globally across your website or locally?

Comment: It's a review widget. I actually need it in a specific page only. So I haven't put it  globally.

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue? @Md.AbdullahAlMamun

Comment: No actually at that time. Maybe other developers on that project handled this.